# Is $c( \mathrm{inf} \{ x : c(x) \ge y \}) = y$, for Cantor function $c : [0,1] \to [0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, cantor-set

Let $c : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), which is constructed by the following procedure.

1. Convert the input into base 3.
2. If the converted input contains 1, replace every digit after the first 1 by 0.
3. Replace all 2s with 1s, and thus the output in base 2.

It is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function#Properties) that the Cantor function is uniformly continuous, but not absolutely continuous.  But my main question is,

> Is $c( \mathrm{inf} \{ x : c(x) \ge y \}) = y$, for Cantor function $c : [0,1] \to [0,1]$?

**My attempt**

If $y$ is a dyadic rational, it holds directly, because I can explicitly find $x$ corresponds to $\mathrm{inf} \{ x : c(x) \ge y \}$.

But if $y$ is an irrational number, then things get complicated, since I'm lost in finding one explicitly. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ be a continuous increasing function. Consider

$$x_*=\inf\{x\in [0,1]| f(x)\ge y\}.$$ If $x_*\not\in \{x\in [0,1]| f(x)\ge y\}$ then it is $f(x_*)<y.$ Now, by definition of infimum, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $x_n\in \{x\in [0,1]| f(x)\ge y\}$ such that $x_n\le x_*+1/n.$ So using that $f$ is increasing we get

$$y\le f(x_n)\le f\left(x_*+\frac 1n\right).$$ Since $f$ is continuous taking limits we get

$$y\le \lim_{n\to \infty}f\left(x_*+\frac 1n\right)=f(x_*).$$ Thus we get a contradiction. So it is

$$x_*=\inf\{x\in [0,1]| f(x)\ge y\}\in \{x\in [0,1]| f(x)\ge y\},$$ from where,

$$f(x_*)\ge y.$$

**Edit**

We will show that $f(x_*)=y$ under the additional assumption that $f(0)=0, f(1)=1.$

First of all, if $y=0$ then $x_*=0$ and we are done.

So we will suppose $0<y<1$ (and thus $x_*>0$). Assume that $f(x_*)>y.$ Since $f$ is continuous there exists $z\in (0,x_*)$ such that $f(z)=y.$ This contradicts the definition of $x_*.$ Thus, we have shown that $f(x_*)=y.$

Finally, consider $y=1.$ Since we have shown that $f(x_*)\ge y=1$ and $0\le f\le 1$ it is $f(x_*)=y=1.$

Comment: Just a minor thing : shouldn't it be 'such that $x_n < x_*+1/n.$'?

Comment: how is $f(x_*)= y$ from $f(x_*)\ge y$?

Comment: The solution was incomplete. Assuming additionally that $f(0)=0,f(1)=1$ we can show that $f(x_*)=y.$ Since the Cantor function satisfies all the conditions the solution is complete.